# How Can I Convert a Glob into an Array of Filenames (not paths) in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I want to expand a glob in zsh into only the filenames, rather than paths, of the matching files. I know that I can do something like this:

```
paths=(/some/path/blah*blah*blah)
typeset -a filenames
for i ({1..$#paths}); do
  filenames[$i]=`basename $paths[$i]`
done
```

But I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a two-step process that uses parameter modifiers:

```
paths=(/some/path/blah*blah*blah)
filenames=($paths[@]:t)
```

but you can also apply the `:t` modifier directly to the glob itself:

```
filenames=( /some/path/blah*blah*blah(:t) )
```

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I was looking for.